# Conditional Probability for a Medical Test

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

There are two test for a disease: one is rapid and the other is slow. Given an infected individual, the rapid test will register positive 40% of the time, while the slow test will register positive 80% of the time: additionally, both tests will be positive 35% of the time.

1. Given an infected person and that the rapid test measures a positive result, what is the probability that the slow test is also positive?

I assumed the tests were independent, giving just 80%. This is incorrect however.

I tried also P(slow) * P(rapid) = 0.80 * 0.40 = 0.32, which was also incorrect.

I also tried P(A|B) = P(A and B)/ P(B) leaving just P(A) = 0.8

I'm not sure how to incorporate the latter half of the information either. Is 35% referring to positive for all tests (infected or uninfected individuals), i.e. false-positive rate?

2. Given an infected person and that the rapid test measures a negative result, what is the chance that the slow test is positive.

Same problem here. Why would the results of a rapid test affect the results of a slow test--shouldn't it just be 80%?

Comment: We are given no information regarding how the two tests may be correlated (other than through actual infection). That is to say, we have no information which would tell us that a true rapid test predicted a true or a false slow test. Why do you believe the $80\%$ answer is incorrect?

Comment: For 1), if $A$ denotes the probability that the slow test is positive given an infected patient and $B$ the probability that the rapid test is positive given an infected patient then the probability that the slow test is positive given an infected patient with a positive rapid test is $P(A|B)=P(A \cap B)/P(B)=0.35/0.4=7/8$ right? I don't see the problem, maybe I'm tired

Comment: Oh, I think I may have misunderstood the "both tests positive $35\%$ of the time." clause.  I read that as saying both tests show a positive (possible true, possibly false) with probability $.35$.  Did you mean rather that "given an infected person, the probability that both tests come up positive is $.35$"?  If so, that's very different.

Comment: Hello, thanks both for your help. I know 80% is incorrect based on the autograder function for this problem. And lulu I also was confused about that. I think it is the second one you wrote. Also, @Evariste, thanks for that explanation. I didn't think to put (∩) = 0.35 for some silly reason...

Comment: Yes, that's the right answer, given the second interpretation of that clause.

Comment: How about question 2? I thought it would be: if A denotes probability that slow test is positive given an infected person, and B the probability that the rapid test is negative given an infected patient, than the probability a slow test is positive given an infected patient with a negative rapid test is: (|)=(∩)/()=0.8*(1-0.4)/(1-0.4)=8/10, but still it's not right.

Comment: There are $4$ cases\, $(+,+), (+,-),(-,+),(-,-)$ according to how the two tests come up.  The data (interpreted correctly) lets you compute the probabilities of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reading is that for an infected person

- there is a probability of $0.35$ both tests show positive
- there is a probability of $0.4-0.35=0.05$ the fast test shows positive and the slow test negative
- there is a probability of $0.8-0.35=0.45$ the fast test shows negative and the slow test positive
- there is a probability of $1-0.35-0.05-0.45=0.15$ both tests show negative

So the answers are:

1. $\frac{0.35}{0.35+0.05}=0.875$ for the probability that the slow test is positive, given an infected person and that the rapid test measures a positive result
2. $\frac{0.45}{0.45+0.15}=0.75$ for the probability that the slow test is positive, given an infected person and that the rapid test measures a negative result

Comment: Great! Thanks, Henry. How did you come up with the bottom three bullets?

Comment: @julien I have added some subtraction

Comment: Can someone help me with this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4173140/940994