# Bayes Rule for Disease Testing Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

There are two tests for a disease, one is rapid and the other is slow. Given that an individual is infected, the rapid test will register positive 40% of the time, while the slow test will register positive 80% of the time; additionally, both tests will be positive $35\%$ of the time.

Suppose in the above example that people not infected always test negative for both tests.

**Question 1**. Assume currently, $20\%$ of the population has the virus. Use Bayes theorem to calculate the chance that a person has the virus conditioned on getting negative results for both tests?

I made this table assuming 100 people tested (rapid test on left; slow on right) to try to calculate this: added 12/92 + 4/84 as those are the people with the disease who tested negative. This answer was incorrect, however.

[image: Table]

**Question 2 (independent of question 1)**. Of the people in the population who are tested, 75% of their results from the slow test are positive. What is the chance that a persons has the virus conditioned on getting negative result on the slow test?

For this one, I altered the right table slightly to be 15|4 for the disease column, and did 5/85--also incorrect.

Comment: Continuation of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173078/conditional-probability-for-a-medical-test/

Comment: The tests are not conditionally independent.  Your tables do not incorporate this data :  "...additionally both tests will be positive $35\%$ of the time." . $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(R\mid I)&=0.40 \\ \mathsf P(S\mid I)&=0.80 \\\mathsf P(R\cap S\mid I)&=0.35\\ \mathsf P(R\cup S\mid I^{\small\complement})&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks for your input. I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the table to be honest.